# Gitlab 6.7 fails to create account when using LDAP Login

Tags: ldap, omniauth, gitlab

I'm currently trying to setup Gitlab 6.7 as a fresh install as well as upgrading from version 6.6. While doing so I ran into the following error:
When logging in with an LDAP account, which is not in Gitlab yet, the login fails with the message containing the words

> Could not authorize you from LDAP because: "Validation failed username only letters, digits & '_' '-' '.' allowed. Letter should be first".

Hence the upgraded version still works with existing accounts.

After having a look at the code in GitHub I suspect that the root cause is that the generation of the Gitlab username changed.
To me it looks like before it was the first part of the email address (everything up to @) and now it seems to be the uid, but in my case the uid is an email address containing an @ character.

As I do not have any other value in LDAP with uniquely identifies a user, I am required to use the uid/mail.

Anyone has a hint how to proceed here?
Thanks

LDAP:

```
objectClass    person
givenName      Jane
sn             Doe
cn             Jane Doe
uid            jane.doe@example.com
mail           jane.doe@example.com
```

Gitlab.yml 6.6:

```
ldap:
    enabled: true
    host: 'ldaphost.example.com'
    base: 'o=example.com'
    port: 636
    uid: 'uid'
    method: 'ssl' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    #bind_dn: ''
    #password: '_the_password_of_the_bind_user'
    # If allow_username_or_email_login is enabled, GitLab will ignore everything
    # after the first '@' in the LDAP username submitted by the user on login.
    #
    # Example:
    # - the user enters 'jane.doe@example.com' and 'p@ssw0rd' as LDAP credentials;
    # - GitLab queries the LDAP server with 'jane.doe' and 'p@ssw0rd'.
    #
    # If you are using "uid: 'userPrincipalName'" on ActiveDirectory you need to
    # disable this setting, because the userPrincipalName contains an '@'.
    allow_username_or_email_login: false
```

Gitlab.yml 6.7:

```
ldap:
    enabled: true
    host: 'ldaphost.example.com'
    port: 636
    uid: 'uid'
    method: 'ssl' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    #bind_dn: '_the_full_dn_of_the_user_you_will_bind_with'
    #password: '_the_password_of_the_bind_user'
    # If allow_username_or_email_login is enabled, GitLab will ignore everything
    # after the first '@' in the LDAP username submitted by the user on login.
    #
    # Example:
    # - the user enters 'jane.doe@example.com' and 'p@ssw0rd' as LDAP credentials;
    # - GitLab queries the LDAP server with 'jane.doe' and 'p@ssw0rd'.
    #
    # If you are using "uid: 'userPrincipalName'" on ActiveDirectory you need to
    # disable this setting, because the userPrincipalName contains an '@'.
    allow_username_or_email_login: false

    # Base where we can search for users
    #
    #   Ex. ou=People,dc=gitlab,dc=example
    #
    base: 'o=example.com'

    # Filter LDAP users
    #
    #   Format: RFC 4515
    #   Ex. (employeeType=developer)
    #
    user_filter: ''
```

Comment: facing the same problem. I tried to change the "format: { with: Gitlab::Regex.username_regex," to default_regex and than the user was created based com a email login, but the admin page started to raise error 500. Looks like this is a current gitlab limitation. In a scenario where you want do have ldap and email as username with diferent doamains, some hacking is needed. For now my knowledge in Ruby is very poor.

Comment: Using the E-Mail as the user name might not be possible due to the format of the ssh cloning path (e.g. ssh git@<host>:jane.doe@example.com/myproject.git).
Probably these special characters should be replaced by '_'

Comment: @RubenTrancoso I just had a look at the code. The problem arises be cause of lines 88-90 in the file _lib/gitlab/ldap/user.rb_. Neither do I have a nickname in LDAP, nor I'm using Active directory, which would have the field samaccountname. If you comment out these line, users will be created and their username will be the start of the email address (as it used to be). In your case you could do two things: 1. Replace illegal characters with underscores or 2. create a UUID as username.